# How to instantiate a Backend on Azure DevOps Pipelines?

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So I have a webapp consisting of the following Stack: `Node.js + Express.js` for the Backend, `MongoDB` for DBMS, `Angular` for Frontend. Now I want to test my webapp in Azure DevOps completely. The `ng test` executes successfully, but my `ng e2e` tests fail because the Backend is not running on localhost:3000. Could you give me some direction or ideally some azure-pipelines.yml code which would point me in the correct direction?
As far as I understand myself I should instantiate Docker Images (so called [service containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)) of mongo with

```
containers:
  - container: mongo
    image: mongo
```

and then somehow run the backend. If I run nodemon it will just keep on running, which is not a viable solution for me. Also how do I add my DB data onto the DevOps instance? How do I solve this problem?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54934007/install-mongodb-on-azure-devops-host-for-testrun) question does not solve my problem.

Comment: Ideally you would have multiple url for different environnement. Once in production, your backend will not run on `localhost:3000`, right ? If you already have different environement, you could use the flag `--environnement=some environnement` to specify that environnement so your `ng e2e` will know what config to get.

Comment: @Nicolas that isn't decided yet, but probably in production the backend will run on a separate server. So far for testing I would prefer the backend to run on localhost:3000

Comment: Do you have a public testing environnement, one that is accessible from Azure Pipeline ? If so, you could create yourself a `/environments/environement.staging.ts` with the correct address and then use the flag `--environement=staging`

Comment: @Nicolas no I don't as far as I know. Edit: I don't use environments at this stage of development yet. Should I?

Comment: That might be the way to go, I don't see any other immediate solution. Note that i'm not a Pro DevOps.